# Batch - parse multi-line command output in variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, multiline

I have a batch I use to run multiple SQL scripts and record their output in a single text file (SQL_results.txt). This is the block that will run a script and check the results for errors at the beginning of the output (errors will always be on a single line, starting with "Msg"):

```
SQLCMD command_to_run_a_script > error.txt
set /p result=<error.txt
set result=%result:~0,3%
if ""%result%""==""Msg"" exit
type error.txt >> SQL_results.txt
del error.txt
```

It is worth noting that the output has a dynamic number of lines and may exceed the variable char limit and that the "Msg..." line may not always be the first.

I tried this for a test of doing the check in a variable, but it will only write the last line of the output for each line:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('SQLCMD command_to_run_a_script') do (set VAR=%%i & ECHO %VAR%>> SQL_results.txt)
```

Could something like this be done by parsing the results line-by-line in trying to find one that begins with "Msg", in a variable instead of having to create & delete a text file for each script?

Comment: You know, I bet `sqlcmd` will exit zero on success, non-zero with errors.  Check the documentation to be sure.  But if that's true, you could just `sqlcmd command_to_run_a_script || echo There was an error.` or similar.  If the exit code is unreliable, you could also `sqlcmd command_to_run_a_script | findstr /i "^Msg" >NUL && echo Output contained an error.  Something went wrong.`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, SQLCMD will indeed exit on error if the -b switch is used, so I can work with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a variable will hold only one line it's not quite clear to me what you intend.

To filter only lines with errors into a file:

```
SQLCMD command_to_run_a_script|Findstr "^MSG" > error.txt
```

Store MSG lines in an array and output at the end

```
@Echo off&Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set cnt=0
For /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'SQLCMD command_to_run_a_script ^|Findstr "^MSG" '
) Do (
  Set /A cnt+=1
  Set "MSG[!Cnt!]=%%A"
)
Echo had %cnt% MSG lines
For /l %%C in (1,1,%cnt%) Do Set MSG[%%C]
```

Comment: The idea is to record all the results for all the scripts in the SQL_results.txt file. When an error occurs, this should also get recorded, but then the batch should stop running. rojo's comment changed the way I ran the scripts and got me to the desired result, but thank you for your help